# Systemd sequencial stop of template unit instances

Tags: linux, systemd, systemctl, operating-system, systemd-service

I have a template unit that that I have to created in order to start/stop some services running an a given port. something like `service@8080.service`, `service@8081.service`.

```
[Unit]
After=network.target
PartOf=services.target

[Service]
ExecStart=app run --port %i
ExecStopPost=sleep 5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I created a target to manage all these services at once.

```
cat services.target
[Unit]

Wants=service@8081.service service@8082.service
```

That works fine.
They are all delivering the same API so in order to disrupt services, I want to restart only one process at the same time.

. One solution could be to use `After` in the `unit template`, but this is not very flexible since I could have more or less of these processes running, If I remove one, I might break the dependency chain....
So the only solution that I found was to write a bash script that stop/start the instances one by one, with a `sleep` in the between.
It means that can use the `target` to `stop` and `start` but not `restart`... which is not conveniant.

What other option(s) do I have ?
Possibility to use `notify`?